# Using simple salesforce to get field names for each salesforce object in a loop

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I'm using simple_salesforce to get a list of all field names for an object.

I have the following

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

sf = Salesforce(username = username, password = pass....) #Connecting to sf

#I'm using salesforce object api names to get all the fields that belong to that object
Api_names = ["Account", "Contact", "Campaign"]

desc = {}
for obj in Api_names:
    if obj == "Account":
        desc = sf.Account.describe()
    elif obj == "Contact":
        desc = sf.Contact.describe()
    elif obj == "Campaign":
        desc = sf.Campaign.describe()

    field_names_list_1 = [field['name'] for field in desc['fields']]

    #do something with the list... for now, I'm just adding break
    break
```

I want to write something like this

```
Api_names = ["Account", "Contact", "Campaign"]
for obj in Api_names:
    desc = sf.obj.describe()
```

But it's treating obj as an api name. I did try the soql way

```
query = sf.query("SELECT QualifiedApiName FROM FieldDefinition WHERE
EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName IN ('{0}')".format("Account"))

field_names_list_2 = []
for i in range(0, query['totalSize']):
    field_names_list_2.append(query['records'][i]["QualifiedApiName"])
```

But, for Account object, `field_names_list_1` and `field_names_list_2` have different lengths. field_names_list_1 contains all the fields but field_names_list_2 is missing some fields. Not sure why.

What can I change in `sf.obj.describe()` so it's treats obj as an actual variable instead of a salesforce object name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getattr()` to dynamically acquire an object proxy in `simple_salesforce`:

```
api_names = ["Account", "Contact", "Campaign"]
for obj in Api_names:
    desc = getattr(sf, obj).describe()
```